# QGIS server WFS/OAPIF Post request hangs on: WARNING [13]: attr: name=Description idx=0 value=Test

Tags: qgis-server, wfs-t, docker, ogc-api-features

### Short

I am currently experiencing QGIS server with transactions using WFS/OAPIF, namely for doing POST requests.

To to this end, I'm using a Docker image (either [[1](https://hub.docker.com/r/opengisch/qgis-server)] or [[2](https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server)]; the same problem as the one described below occurs with both images, but they use slightly different URLs. I will only show the logs of the first image, unless otherwise specified.).

QGIS server is hanging on this error each time I do a POST request from a client:

```
******************** New request ***************
... stuff
WARNING [13]: attr: name=Description idx=0 value=Test
```

And the PostGIS database seems to open a transaction on that request, but it never receives the statement to execute:

```
LOG:  statement: SET extra_float_digits=3; SET application_name='QGIS3 server'; SET datestyle='ISO'
LOG:  statement: SET statement_timeout = 20000
LOG:  statement: BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

### Detailed

I've successfully set up a QGIS project with some very simple PostGIS data layers (2 point layers and a polygon layer).

I configured all the services (WMS, WMTS, WFS, OAPIF) with no fancy parameters.
The project is valid when I hit the <kbd>Launch</kbd> button in the Test Configuration section of the QGIS server tab.
I can successfully access all the services, and I can see the data.

From whatever client, everything is fine for GET operations.

In order to enable transactions, I also ticked "Update / Insert / Delete" columns in the WFS/OAPIF tab (Menu: "Project > Properties > QGISSserver") in my QGIS server project:

[image]

So I must be able to do some transactions using one of these two services, such as creating a new feature for example.

### Issues

Here are the issues with both services:

#### OAPIF

By using QGIS as a client, when I connect to this OAPIF endpoint in the "WFS/OGC API - Features" in the Data Manager: http://localhost:8010/wfs3/?MAP=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs
I can successfully add my 3 layers.

But each time I click the save button to add a new feature with all of its attributes filled (e.g. a new point feature in the `pt_from_csv` layer) the following "Commit errors" is shown in a pop-up by QGIS:

```
Could not commit changes to layer pt_from_csv

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature not added.
```

It's not super verbose, so I checked the QGIS server logs corresponding to that request:

```
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 20218:47 INFO Server[13]: ******************** New request ***************
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: Request URL: http://localhost:8010/wfs3/?MAP=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: Environment:
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: ------------------------------------------------
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: SERVER_NAME: localhost
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: REQUEST_URI: /wfs3/?MAP=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: SCRIPT_NAME: /qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: HTTPS: 
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: REMOTE_ADDR: 172.22.0.1
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: SERVER_PORT: 8010
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: QUERY_STRING: MAP=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: CONTENT_TYPE: text/xml
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: REQUEST_METHOD: POST
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
my_app-qgis-server-1  | Headers:
my_app-qgis-server-1  | ------------------------------------------------
my_app-qgis-server-1  | "Host" :  "localhost:8010"
my_app-qgis-server-1  | "User-Agent" :  "Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/32806/Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 WARNING Server[13]: Error parsing post data as XML: at line 1, column 532: error occurred while parsing element. Assuming urlencoded query string sent in the post body.
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: <TRANSACTION XMLNS:"http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.qgis.org/gml http://localhost:8010/wfs3/?MAP=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: AMP;REQUEST:DescribeFeatureType
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: AMP;SERVICE:WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: AMP;TYPENAME:pt_from_csv" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" service="WFS"><Insert xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"><pt_from_csv xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml"><Description xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">Test</Description><Number_of_samples xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">10</Number_of_samples><Sampling_rate_Hz xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">2</Sampling_rate_Hz><Internal_ID xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">fig-1552</Internal_ID><Data_grösse_Byte xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">4512778</Data_grösse_Byte><State xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">Zuerich</State><Year xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">2022</Year><id xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">1102</id><geometry xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml"><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:2056"><gml:pos srsDimension="2">2684331.30362764792516828 1245039.15295048733241856</gml:pos></gml:Point></geometry></pt_from_csv></Insert></Transaction>
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: AMP;VERSION:1.0.0
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: MAP:/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: SERVICE:WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 WARNING Server[13]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
my_app-qgis-server-1  | <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
my_app-qgis-server-1  |  <ServiceException code="OperationNotSupported">Please add or check the value of the REQUEST parameter</ServiceException>
my_app-qgis-server-1  | </ServiceExceptionReport>
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:18:47 INFO Server[13]: Request finished in 1 ms
```

Also, there isn't any single line in the PostGIS database log. So the transaction doesn't reach the database.

#### WFS

Now, when I connect to the WFS endpoint in the "WFS/OGC API - Features" in the Data Manager: http://localhost:8010/ogc/My_project?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
(which is a proxy of http://localhost:8010/ogc/?map=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&Request=GetCapabilities)
I can also add my 3 layers successfully.

But each time I click the save button to add a new feature with all of its attributes filled (e.g. a point feature in the `pt_from_csv` layer) QGIS freezes for at least 1 minute (absolutely nothing responds), then it shows the same "Commit errors" pop-up as before, along with a network error:

```
WARNING    Network request http://localhost:8010/ogc/My_project?SERVICE=WFS timed out
```

This is the QGIS server log corresponding to that request:

```
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: ******************** New request ***************
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: Request URL: http://localhost:8010/ogc/My_project?map=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: Environment:
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: ------------------------------------------------
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: SERVER_NAME: localhost
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: REQUEST_URI: /ogc/My_project?SERVICE=WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: SCRIPT_NAME: /qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: HTTPS: 
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: REMOTE_ADDR: 172.31.0.1
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: SERVER_PORT: 8010
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: QUERY_STRING: map=/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: CONTENT_TYPE: text/xml
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: REQUEST_METHOD: POST
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
my_app-qgis-server-1  | Headers:
my_app-qgis-server-1  | ------------------------------------------------
my_app-qgis-server-1  | "Host" :  "localhost:8010"
my_app-qgis-server-1  | "User-Agent" :  "Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/32806/Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: MAP:/io/data/My_project/My_project.qgs
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: REQUEST:Transaction
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: REQUEST_BODY:<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" version="1.1.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" service="WFS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.qgis.org/gml http://localhost:8010/ogc/My_project?SERVICE=WFS&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;TYPENAME=pt_from_csv" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Insert xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"><pt_from_csv xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml"><Description xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">Test</Description><Number_of_samples xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">10</Number_of_samples><Sampling_rate_Hz xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">2</Sampling_rate_Hz><Internal_ID xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">fid-1009</Internal_ID><Data_grösse_Byte xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">4678211</Data_grösse_Byte><State xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">Zuerich</State><Year xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">2022</Year><id xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml">1101</id><geometry xmlns="http://www.qgis.org/gml"><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:2056"><gml:pos srsDimension="2">2684037.25046077255400062 1244792.54637890809139609</gml:pos></gml:Point></geometry></pt_from_csv></Insert></Transaction>
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: SCHEMALOCATION:http://www.qgis.org/gml http://localhost:8010/ogc/My_project?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=pt_from_csv
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: SERVICE:WFS
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 INFO Server[13]: VERSION:1.1.0
my_app-qgis-server-1  | proj_create: Error 1029 (File not found or invalid): pipeline: Pipeline: Bad step definition: proj=hgridshift (File not found or invalid)
my_app-qgis-server-1  | 07:49:10 WARNING [13]: attr: name=Description idx=0 value=Test
```

After that very last `WARNING` line, the QGIS server docker service becomes definitely unresponsive, that means I **have** to shut it down and re-up it again.

But now, the database logs show something:

```
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.710 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SELECT regclass('pg_class')::oid AS oidselect;BEGIN;DECLARE oidcursor BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT regclass('pg_class')::oid AS oidbinarycursor;FETCH FORWARD 1 FROM oidcursor;CLOSE oidcursor;COMMIT;
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.710 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SELECT postgis_version()
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.716 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SELECT postgis_geos_version(), postgis_proj_version()
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.716 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SELECT has_schema_privilege(n.oid, 'usage') AND has_table_privilege(t.oid, 'select') AND has_table_privilege(l.oid, 'select') FROM pg_namespace n, pg_class t, pg_class l WHERE n.nspname = 'topology' AND t.relnamespace = n.oid AND l.relnamespace = n.oid AND t.relname = 'topology' AND l.relname = 'layer'
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.717 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SELECT has_table_privilege(c.oid, 'select') AND has_table_privilege(f.oid, 'select') FROM pg_class c, pg_class f, pg_namespace n, pg_extension e WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND c.relname = 'pointcloud_columns' AND f.relnamespace = n.oid AND f.relname = 'pointcloud_formats' AND n.oid = e.extnamespace AND e.extname = 'pointcloud'
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.717 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SELECT has_table_privilege(c.oid, 'select') FROM pg_class c, pg_namespace n, pg_type t WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND n.oid = t.typnamespace AND c.relname = 'raster_columns' AND t.typname = 'raster'
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.717 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SET extra_float_digits=3; SET application_name='QGIS3 server'; SET datestyle='ISO'
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.717 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: SET statement_timeout = 20000
my_app-db-1  | 2023-05-11 07:49:10.717 UTC [886] LOG:  statement: BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

but it hangs on forever at this point.

Also, the web server ([nginx](https://github.com/opengisch/qgis-docker/blob/master/conf/qgis-server-nginx.conf)) shows:

```
[error] 29#29: *62 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: _, request: "POST /ogc/My_project?SERVICE=WFS HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.22.0.3:9993", host: "localhost:8010"
```

And with the camptocamp Docker image, the embedded web server (Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured) shows some kind of same timeout signs:

```
my_app-c2c-qgis  |  [warn] [pid 14] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
my_app-c2c-qgis  |  [error] [pid 14] End of script output before headers: qgis-mapserv-wrapper
my_app-c2c-qgis  | 40046815 - 172.31.0.1 - - [11/May/2023:07:45:10 +0000] "POST /?MAP=/etc/qgisserver/My_project/My_project.qgs&SERVICE=WFS HTTP/1.1" 500 801 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/32806/Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
my_app-c2c-qgis  |  [warn] [pid 12] mod_fcgid: process 69 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

#### Question

How can I make either the WFS or the OAPIF endpoint work for transactions?

Comment: OGC API Features standard does not support transactions yet. You can follow the development of the standard here https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features/tree/master/extensions/transactions. WFS-T should work, but there is something wrong with your installation, and that has to do with coordinate systems and Proj. Read the error `proj_create: Error 1029 (File not found or invalid): pipeline: Pipeline: Bad step definition: proj=hgridshift (File not found or invalid)`

Comment: You are perfectly right about the OAPIF, that's probably why it doesn't work.
The issue with the WFS may be due to `proj`, indeed, but curiously, I do not see any projection related issues or error with the c2c image.... I will continue investigating in that direction.

Comment: The geometry in the insert is in EPSG:2056. Is that the native SRS of the feature type?

Comment: Yes the SRID reported by PostGIS is 2056. I also have to say that the same `hgridshift` error is shown in the c2c Docker image. I simply missed it before. So the two images are consistent.